# Adding class on selected list item after removal

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few list items that appear as white boxes. Number 60 appears with a red background, however. At the start of the script I set that list item's ID into a variable called "boxID". When the left keyboard button is pressed this red background (class) is then removed, and the "boxID" is subtracted by 1, making it 59. However, when I try to add the same class to the list item containing the new "boxID" ID, all boxes become red, as if it is unable to select list item with ID #59 and just selects all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var boxID = $('li.selected').attr('id');

   $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            $('li').attr('id', boxID).removeClass('selected');
            boxID -= 1;
            $('li').attr('id', boxID).addClass('selected');
        }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting the element wrong.  Change this:

```
$('li').attr('id', boxID).addClass('selected');
```

to:

```
$('li#' + boxID).addClass('selected');
```

The way you've written it, you're telling jQuery to change all the `li` elements' `id` attribute to `boxID`, and then after that, add the `selected` class to them all.

Comment: Oh. When you say so I actually do remember using .attr to change values and such, but I've apparently forgotten ;) Thank you for the clarification and reminder.

Comment: @Millenille No problem. Feel free to accept this answer (and upvote it!) if it worked for you. :)